# Is it necessary to set up Workflow Manager on computers joined to a domain?

Tags: dns, workflow-manager-1.x

I'm trying to set up a multi-node Workflow Manager farm here.

I have 3 machines with Workflow Manager installed, and are not joined to any domain.

I tried running the Get-WFFarmStatus command after I created a farm, and got warning messages that goes like:

`WARNING: Endpoint https://nodename:12290/ is not responding: The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel.`

I'm guessing that I need a domain certificate for this to work?

Any advice is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the certificates from that other server to the trusted root certification authorities?
It's probably because the SSL certificate is not trusted from your client server ?

Comment: First of all, thanks for the response.
I tried adding certs in their respective cert stores and the warning went away.

But I'm in a situation which I will not know what other machines would join the farm, or leave the farm.

So I was thinking of creating some kind of wildcard certificate that would trust all the machines joined the farm.

Does that mean I need to be in a domain to create this kind of certificate?

Comment: I would consider creating a certificate that all machines trust and signing machine certificates with this. You can automate all these processes, no matter which choice you go with.